# Creating an Array of Objects from an XML file - Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to create an array of objects in JavaScript and fill each from an XML files.
The XML file has already been loaded in a previous function. However when i try to push the new product i get an error in console that x[i] is undefined.

My code is:

```
function CreateProductObject() {
  function productObject(name, brand, price, info, material, photo) {
    this.name = name;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.price = price;
    this.info = material;
    this.photo = photo;
  }
  var productArray = [];

  var numOfProducts = CountProducts(productType);
  console.log(productType + " needs to be Displayed: " + numOfProducts);

  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(productType);

  for (i = 0; i <= numOfProducts; i++) {
    productArray.push(
      new productObject(
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("BRAND")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("INFO")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("MATERIAL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        x[i].getElementsByTagName("PHOTO")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
      ),
    );

    console.log(productArray[i].name);
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is `CountProducts`? Nearly certain this is an off-by-one problem (use `i <`, not `i <=`)

Comment: Ooof silly me, yes that was the problem :P how do i mark you as the correct answer?

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic and should be closed, not answered, so it's not something I should write an answer for

Comment: no worries, ill delete the question. appreciate your help none the less!

Answer (score -2):

You haven't declared `x`, hence it is undefined.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I can always edit my answer if things do change @VicJordan

Comment: it is declared above the loop. the issue was a simple mistake of <= instead of <. Thank you anyway

Comment: @user10227614 Ah ok, was only answering based on the example presented. Glad you got it sorted out 